# SQL - temporarily set default date when parsing time as datetime in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

if I do

```
SELECT CAST('11:30 pm' AS datetime)
```

I get 1900-01-01 23:30:00.000

but if I do

```
SELECT PARSE('11:30 PM' AS datetime using 'en-gb')
```

I get 2019-08-20 23:30:00.000

i.e. parse gives today's date.

Is it possible to modify the default date that parsing a time value gives to 1900-01-01 (similar to cast)?

The reason I want this is because I'm looping through a large number of columns and want to determine whether or not they should be set to dates, times or datetimes so if every date in a datetime column is 1900-01-01 I can certain that i need to convert it to a time column (because I will never deal with the date 1900-01-01) but there is a possibility that all the dates in a column are set to today's date and I shouldn't be removing the date section of the column.

For example one column could be:

```
11:01
11:30
11:40
```

but another column could be

```
20-08-2019 11:00
20-08-2019 11:05
20-08-2019 11:10
```

I want to run the same procedure against both columns to get them in the right format. 
So the first column should stay as a time column and the 2nd should be a datetime column.

As I say I have several columns so I don't want to manually look through each one to determine if it should be a datetime or time but if I could have the date set to 1900-01-01 when I parse a time to datetime (similar to cast) I'll be able to see which columns should have the date part removed.

I have something similar to deal with datetimes where the time part should be removed: I simply check if there exists at least one time which isn't 00:00 and if there isn't I'll convert it to do a date.

I need to use PARSE as I'm unsure of the formats the dates will be in and PARSE is significantly more flexible than CONVERT or CAST (from my experience).

Comment: "I need to use PARSE as I'm unsure of the formats the dates will be in" How do you expect to interpret the following string? `01-02-2019 10:23:30`? I can think of at least 4 different datetime values that this string can be converted to, none of them has any precedence over the other. So what would it be - 10 am or 10 pm? January second or February 1st?

Comment: I would parse the column as datetime using en-gb first, then en-us, if both succeed then it's impossible to determine if it should be a us or uk date format so I'll not convert the column at all. I have the necessary steps to stop this from happening the only issue is when i parse a time as a datetime

Comment: Still, us or uk doesn't change the fact that `10:23:30` can be either 10 am or 10 pm.

Comment: so, you're storing dates/times in varchar-typed columns, and want to fix that?  Also, be aware that PARSE is much slower than CAST/CONVERT.

Answer (score 2):

As I saw , it may not be possible because `PARSE()` uses `.NET` with `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` for date and/or time parsing as fixed setting.

You can use `SET LANGUAGE` to set a specific language/culture when using CAST or CONVERT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want a `datetime` value from 1900, but you can use:

```
select convert(datetime, PARSE('11:30 PM' AS time using 'en-gb'))
```

I would be content with a `time` value:

```
select PARSE('11:30 PM' AS time using 'en-gb')
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this wouldn't help me. 11:30 pm is simply an example. There could be another column with a value "2011-10-10 11:30" and in that case I wouldn't want to get rid of the date part, but if every date in a datetime column is 1900-01-01 I'll know it's safe to convert the datetime column to time

Comment: @Anonymous . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with clear sample data and desired results.  This answers the question that was asked here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for value '1900-01-01' as output, you can simply cast as date as below-

```
SELECT CAST('11:30 pm' AS date)
```

Output is-

```
1900-01-01
```